# Prettier does not ignore a folder that have root permissions

Tags: prettier

In my project we have a docker folder that we use to run the container. The issue is that when we run prettier i got this error:

```
[error] Unable to expand directory: .
[error] EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/home/nanez/my-project/docker/data/postgres'
```

This folder need root permissions to access and delete it (using sudo ofc). I already added the whole docker folder to `.prettierignore` and also the specific postgres folder and i still throwing the error. Here my `.prettierignore`:

```
## Deps
node_modules
cache

generated
docker
./docker
/docker/**/*
/docker/*
/docker/data/postgres
```

As you can see, I added the docker folder with all the posibilities that I thought.

If I run prettier with the negative pattern work good, for ex: `npx prettier . '!./docker' --check`. This run all without problem, but I'm wonder why I can't ignore directly with `npx prettier . --check` if already I have the docker folder in the `.prettierignore`.

I'm using WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04LTS.

Thanks :)

Comment: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/11568

Answer (score 1):

As [@Sagnik Pradhan comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7426138/sagnik-pradhan), this is currently (March 2023) an [open issue #11568](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/11568) in Prettier.

From there, there is [only a commented work around](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/11568#issuecomment-1238132646)

> For anyone still facing this issue, I found a workaround. You can specifically ignore the problem file/folder using the command line. For example I was having issues with `.pki` so I ran `prettier . --check '!./.pki'.`

So currently the best answer has already been suggested in the question (and worked for me):

```bash
npx prettier . '!./docker' --check
```